# Cross Validation in StackingClassifier Scikit-Learn

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn, stacking

In Scikit-Learn `StackingClassifier` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html) it's written:

> Note that `estimators_` are fitted on the full `X` while `final_estimator_` is trained using cross-validated predictions of the base estimators using `cross_val_predict`.

> ... the default 5-fold cross validation

My question, why use 5-fold cross-validation only in the final estimator?  why isn't final estimator fitted on the full X' (output from base estimators)?

Answer (score 1):

This includes 2 questions, I will address each of them.

1. We could use cross-validation on the entire system, but that would handicap us a bit too much.

The purpose of cross-validation is to find the optimal parameters, those that allow the model to fit the data well without over-fitting. It suffices that our final estimator does this; there is no need for individually figuring out the settings of all the base estimators. The base estimators can include a bunch of different parameter settings, for example; as well as a selection of different types of classifiers. If any of them are prone to overfitting this should be offset by others not having that problem. As long as the final estimator does not put all of its eggs in the wrong basket, we should be fine (and this is why we need cross-validation here, to make sure this does not happen).

2. We **will** train the final estimator on the full training set -- this happens **after** we find the optimal parameters or set of base estimators using cross-validation. As the name says, cross-*validation* is meant for validating the method. Not for creating the final model.

Comment: I see.., overfitting in each base estimators is not really a problem because there are some estimators. So I think it's okay if we use cross-validation at the "outside" of the stacking model, right? I mean, both base and final estimators are trained with full $X_i$, where $X_i$ is the train set in the $i$-th fold

Answer (score 1):

> My question, why use 5-fold cross-validation only in the final estimator? why isn't final estimator fitted on the full X' (output from base estimators)?

**Short answer:** You probably misunderstood what `StackingClassifier` does (and so did I at first), because the description provided in scikit-learn is prone to misinterpretations (not our fault). If you check the source code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/9aaed498795f68e5956ea762fef9c440ca9eb239/sklearn/ensemble/_stacking.py#L252), you will see that the scikit-learn implementation does stacking correctly.

**Long answer**.

Robby the Belgian's [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/484681) does not address the following prospect, which I guess was your main concern.

Consider training the final estimator. Suppose that one of subestimators overfits pathologically, e.g. it memorises all data seen at training. If subestimators are passed to the final estimator **after being trained on *the whole* dataset**, then the final estimator has no means of telling apart an overfitting subestimator from a genuinely good one, because there is no held-out data left to estimate subestimators' generalisation error. The final estimator will thus rely on the overfit subestimator when making final predictions, thinking that it is the best one, even if truly decent subestimators are available.

As a short digression, let me quote a slightly different justification for holding out some data from subestimators when stacking models. Hastie, Tibshirani & Friedman write in "Elements of Statistical Learning" (page 290):

> ... If [subestimator] $\hat{f}_m(x), \,m=1,\dots,M$ represent the prediction from the best subset of inputs of size $m$ among $M$ total inputs, then linear regression [final estimator] would put all of the weight on the largest model, that is, $\hat{w}_M=1,\, \hat{w}_m=0,\, m<M$. The problem is that we have not put each of the models [subestimators] on the same footing by taking into account their complexity (the number of inputs $m$ in this example).

To put this differently, if the candidate models come from nested model spaces $\mathcal{M}_1 \subset \mathcal{M}_{2} \subset \dots \subset \mathcal{M}_M$ and the training set is reused by the final estimator, then it will always choose the model from $\mathcal{M}_M$ (i.e. the most flexible model), simply because the optimum from the superset is always better than what a subset has to offer. [Digression end]

Now suppose that all subestimators passed to the final estimator are all decent and do not overfit, despite being trained on the whole dataset. Suppose they are "on equal footing" in the sense that they have similar training and generalisation errors: one subestimator is better at some data, another is better at some other data, and so on. If the final estimator sees input in addition to subestimators' predictions at input (`passthrough=True` option), then there is a possibility that the final estimator overfits by memorising which of the subestimators happened to be correct at each input, instead of learning to combine sub-predictions in a generalisable way. In fact, the final estimator can potentially identify datapoints just by subestimators' predictions at them (in case `passthrough=False`). Overfitting of the final estimator can in principle be controlled by tuning its hyperparameters, but this is *not* what `cross_val_predict` does inside `StackingClassifier`.

So, overfitting in stacking can be caused by either of the following:

1. some subestimators overfit and are preferred by the final estimator;
2. the final estimator overfits per se.

Pitfall 2 can be avoided by using a simple model as the final estimator or by tuning it in an outer loop (like GridSearchCV, but I don't think this is a good idea). We have to do this manually.

Pitfall 1 is avoided in `StackingCalssifier` automatically by the fact that at train-time, subestimators are passed to the final estimator **after being trained on *a part* of the dataset**. In other words, the final estimator is trained on the *whole dataset* but its inputs are *out-of-fold* predictions of subestimators. This is precisely what is meant by:

> ... `final_estimator_` is trained using cross-validated predictions of the base estimators using `cross_val_predict`.

In my opinion, "<s>cross-validated</s> out-of-fold predictions" would be a better phrasing.

After the training of the final estimator is done, we can re-train subestimators on the whole dataset to further improve their performance. This is what is meant by

> Note that `estimators_` are fitted on the full `X` ...

Putting these two statements in one sentence causes confusion.